# R datatable buttons export with formated cells

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, formattable

The extensions  `Buttons` works great for shiny application, from `library(DT)`. However it export the data without formatting. Is there a way to export data with format (e.g. percentage, or currency)? [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280333/r-datatable-button-with-conditional-formatting) left unsolved.

Reproducible code

```
library(DT)

data.frame(a = c(1,2),
           b = c(2,3)) %>%
  datatable(extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
     dom = 'Bfrtip',
     buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')) )%>%
   formatPercentage('a') %>%
   formatCurrency('b')
```

Comment: Don't think it is easy. A workaround is to format your data before passing it to datatable. You can use `sprintf` for this.

Comment: Thanks @HubertL, yes I can pre-format the data before sending it to DT, however then I thing it will be taken as a string rather than numeric?

Comment: It will have to live as a string once the currency and percent symbols are added on the other side too. If you are looking to keep it numeric, format the numbers as you choose, and add variable definitions to the column names. It leaves your cells open to mathematical manipulations.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the Buttons extension, you can use the [TableExport](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport) library.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

js_export <- 
"
var $table = $('#DTtable').find('table');
var instance = $table.tableExport({
  formats: ['xlsx'],
  exportButtons: false,
  filename: 'myTable',
  sheetname: 'Sheet1'
});
var exportData0 = instance.getExportData();
var exportData = exportData0[Object.keys(exportData0)[0]]['xlsx'];
instance.export2file(exportData.data, exportData.mimeType, exportData.filename, 
                     exportData.fileExtension, exportData.merges, 
                     exportData.RTL, exportData.sheetname);
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    # put these files in the www subfolder
    tags$script(src = "xlsx.core.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "FileSaver.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "tableexport.min.js")
  ),

  DTOutput("DTtable"),

  actionButton("export", "Export table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$DTtable <- renderDT({
    data.frame(
      a = c(1,2),
      b = c(2,3)
    ) %>%
      datatable() %>%
      formatPercentage('a') %>%
      formatCurrency('b')
  })

  observeEvent(input$export, {
    runjs(js_export)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I would agree that with `js` much customisation can be done. My idea behind was to do it as simple as possible, and since there is an export option to make use of it. Otherwise, one can simply write directly *xlsx* file and customise the cells