# Keep formatting when exporting table with DT (DataTables buttons extension)

Tags: javascript, css, r, datatables, shiny

I made a shiny app where someone uploads a file, some ratios are computed, and those ratios can be formatted using sliders for thresholds. I use `DT::formatStyle` for this and it is working really fine. As far as I understand this function, it creates a callback to handle the conditional formatting.

Then, I want to export the data, using the buttons extension in `DT`. I want to keep the formatting when exporting to pdf or printing. It turns out that this doesn't work: the data is exported without any formatting. I tried to set `exportOptions(list(stripHtml = FALSE))`, but it still doesn't work.

What surprises me as well, is that even when I print directly from Firefox (as File/Print... ; I have tried with Firefox only, and the app will only be run in Firefox), the color is dropped, but font weight is kept. I suspect that I may have to tweak the CSS but I do not know how to do that.

I would like to have a way to make the pdf and/or the print "as is", the closest to what I see in the browser.
Below is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
data("starwars")

ui <- fluidPage(title = "Ratios",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 actionButton("button", "Go"), # Emulates data loading
                 sliderInput("seuil_j", "Threshold J",
                             min = 0,  max = 80, value = 35, step = 0.5)),
    mainPanel( 
      fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                      DT::dataTableOutput("ratios"))))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  donnees_ratios <- reactive({
    req(input$button)
    set.seed(14)
    starwars %>% 
      select(1:10) %>% # DataTables is not happy with list columns
      mutate(signe = sample(c(1, -1), replace = TRUE, size = nrow(.)),
             ratio_j = signe * mass / height) %>% 
      select(name, mass, height, signe, ratio_j, everything())
  })

  output$ratios <- DT::renderDataTable({
    donnees_ratios() %>% 
      creer_DT() %>% 
      formatter_DT(input)
  })
}

creer_DT <- function(donnees) {
  datatable(donnees, 
            rownames = FALSE, 
            class = 'cell-border stripe compact hover',
            extensions = c("Buttons"),
            options = list(
              dom = 'Blfrtip',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = "pdf", 
                     exportOptions = list(stripHtml = FALSE,
                                                     columns = ':visible'),
                     orientation = 'landscape'),
                list(extend = "print", 
                     exportOptions = list(stripHtml = FALSE,
                                          columns = ':visible')),
               "excel", "csv", "colvis"),
              language = list(
                decimal = ",",
                thousands = "&#8239;"  # small unbreakable space
              )
            )
  )
}

formatter_DT <- function(table, input) {
  table %>% 
    formatPercentage(columns = c("ratio_j"),
                     digits = 1L, dec.mark = ",", mark = "&#8239;") %>%
    formatRound(columns = c("height", "mass"),
                digits = 1L, dec.mark = ",", mark = "&#8239;") %>%
    format_seuil("ratio_j", input$seuil_j)
}

format_seuil <- function(table, column, seuil) {
  # Threshold for the aboslute value, and different coloring if higher or lower
  formatStyle(table, column, 
              fontWeight = styleInterval(
                c(-seuil / 100, seuil / 100), c("bold", "normal", "bold")),
              color = styleInterval(
                c(-seuil / 100, seuil / 100), c("red", "black", "orange")
              ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can export to pdf or print, but the display is modified. I could also generate a pdf with `rmarkdown` and `knitr`, but this would be twice the work, and it feels like I miss something using the buttons extension.

I hope that is clear and thanks for helping!

Florian

Comment: I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966732/r-datatable-buttons-export-with-formated-cells) a year ago, but no direct solution found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### tl;dr You cannot keep formatting; you have to write a custom JavaScript function.

`PDF` and `print` buttons have very different behaviors.

#### The `print` button behavior

When you click the `print` button, you use the user agent (in this use case, the browser) to render the `HTML` document as a paged document (PDF). There's a W3C standard named *CSS Paged Media* that defines how CSS rules are applied for paged media.
Theses CSS rules are enclosed in CSS `@media print` at-rule.
There's a comprehensive guide about CSS Paged Media here: [print-css.rocks](https://print-css.rocks/).

Dealing with CSS Paged Media is not straightforward:

- browsers badly implement CSS Paged Media standards; headless user agents (`wkhtmltopdf`, `weasyprint`, `XML Prince`...) are used to generate PDF with CSS Paged Media. Using one of these user agents is quite easy since `pandoc 2.0`: they can replace a `LaTeX` engine.
- when you open a `HTML` file, browsers do not apply `@media print` by default (they apply `@media screen` at-rule). So, it can be hard to figure out `@media print` rules. The only mean I know to track theses rules is to use the Chrome Developer Tools (open the menu, select `More tools` and `Rendering`. In the `Rendering` panel, you can emulate a paged media selecting `print`).

Since you want to use a browser to generate a styled `PDF`, I think CSS paged media rules is an impracticable way. Moreover, using a headless user agent with a dynamic HTML document as a Shiny App is extremely complex. So, my advise is to forget the `print` button.

#### The `PDF` button behavior

`DataTables` library relies on `pdfmake` JavaScript library to generate a PDF file. You can apply custom styles passing a JavaScript function to the [`customize` option of the `pdfHtml5` button](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdfHtml5). This function customizes the document object sent to the [`pdfmake` API](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake).

In order to understand the structure of the `JSON` document object passed by `DataTables` to `pdfmake`, you can output it to the browser console:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
data("starwars")

ui <- fluidPage(title = "Ratios",
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                               actionButton("button", "Go"), # Emulates data loading
                               sliderInput("seuil_j", "Threshold J",
                                           min = 0,  max = 80, value = 35, step = 0.5)),
                  mainPanel( 
                    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                                    DT::dataTableOutput("ratios"))))
                )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  donnees_ratios <- reactive({
    req(input$button)
    set.seed(14)
    starwars %>% 
      select(1:10) %>% # DataTables is not happy with list columns
      mutate(signe = sample(c(1, -1), replace = TRUE, size = nrow(.)),
             ratio_j = signe * mass / height) %>% 
      select(name, mass, height, signe, ratio_j, everything())
  })

  output$ratios <- DT::renderDataTable({
    donnees_ratios() %>% 
      creer_DT() %>% 
      formatter_DT(input)
  })
}

creer_DT <- function(donnees) {
  datatable(donnees, 
            rownames = FALSE, 
            class = 'cell-border stripe compact hover',
            extensions = c("Buttons"),
            options = list(
              dom = 'Blfrtip',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = "pdf", 
                     exportOptions = list(stripHtml = FALSE,
                                          columns = ':visible'),
                     orientation = 'landscape',
                     customize = JS("function(doc){console.dir(doc);}")),
                list(extend = "print", 
                     exportOptions = list(stripHtml = FALSE,
                                          columns = ':visible')),
                "excel", "csv", "colvis"),
              language = list(
                decimal = ",",
                thousands = "&#8239;"  # small unbreakable space
              )
            )
  )
}

formatter_DT <- function(table, input) {
  table %>% 
    formatPercentage(columns = c("ratio_j"),
                     digits = 1L, dec.mark = ",", mark = "&#8239;") %>%
    formatRound(columns = c("height", "mass"),
                digits = 1L, dec.mark = ",", mark = "&#8239;") %>%
    format_seuil("ratio_j", input$seuil_j)
}

format_seuil <- function(table, column, seuil) {
  # Threshold for the aboslute value, and different coloring if higher or lower
  formatStyle(table, column, 
              fontWeight = styleInterval(
                c(-seuil / 100, seuil / 100), c("bold", "normal", "bold")),
              color = styleInterval(
                c(-seuil / 100, seuil / 100), c("red", "black", "orange")
              ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can modify a default style. Here's one example changing the font color of the `tableHeader` style:

```
customize = JS("function(doc){doc.styles.tableHeader.color='yellow';}"))
```

For further customization, you have to write your own JavaScript function. Here's an example to format the fifth column with percent:

```
customize = JS("function(doc){doc.content[1].table.body.forEach(function(el,idx){if(idx>0){el[4].text=String((parseFloat(el[4].text)*100).toFixed(1))+'%'}})}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It felt that it should be easy, but sadly it is not...

Comment: Hi RLesur, thank you for the elaborate explanation. It perfectly works for formatting headers and columns etc, but I have a similar formatting problem, but then with html in the values - namely, I want to print to pdf multiline cells. One cell for example holds `"A</br>B</br>C</br>D</br>E</br>F"`. Which `JS()` function do I need to pass to the `customize` argument to have the `</br>` be read and printed accordingly? If you want I can post a regex and open a new question?

Comment: Hi @Peter, I'm sorry, I won't have time in the next days. I think you should post a new question on SO. It would be easier for you to get an answer.

Comment: Hi @RLesur, thanks for your response. I posted a new question on SO.