# R save table with html tags to excel

Tags: html, r, shiny, dt, rhandsontable

I have a R shiny table with html tags in the cells. I can render the table with `rhandsontable` package on the web content. But is there any way to allow user to download the table to excel with rendered format, instead of having html tags in the excel content?

Comment: Check `DT` package, download button extension

Comment: Just checked `DT button extension` function, all the format by html tags will disappear with only plain text if using DT button extension. I would like to hear more suggestions, `rhandsontable`would be ideal.

Comment: Update!! I was able to use `htmlTable` package to render dataframe with html tags. The downside is that I could only download the table on a html page, instead of excel. I have to manually copy and past the table from html page to excel, and would like to hear other solutions.

Comment: You could try the TableExport library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966732/r-datatable-buttons-export-with-formated-cells/54350639#54350639