# Copy formatted text from datatable in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, copy, dt

I have a `datatable` made of four columns and multiple rows. Cells can contain strings with substrings in **`bold`**.

I'm trying to find a way to `copy` (clipboard) the datatable and then being able to `paste` it in a Word document. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966732/r-datatable-buttons-export-with-formated-cells) about the `TableExport` library (but it's not about copying datatable content here) and others, but apparently it looks like there is no simple way to do it.

I first tried to look at a solution with the `Buttons` extension directly in the datatable, but apparently there is no option to keep the formatting.

If there is no solution, could anyone give some hints about a `javascript` alternative keeping the whole structure (row, columns, header) and formatted text in the final destination (Word)?

**EDIT**
I found a workaround using the new id (found in the Inspector tab) of the filtered datatable. It consists of "DataTables_Table_" + number of current rows. I have this reactive datatable:

**In app.R**

```
datasetInput <- reactive({
    datatable(df.table_cs %>% filter(...),
              rownames = FALSE,
              filter = 'top', 
              selection = "none",
              ...
  })

// When the copy button is pressed:
observeEvent(input$copy_btn, {
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'cypFiltered',
                              message = paste0('DataTables_Table_', nrow(datasetInput()$x$data)))  
})
```

**In script.js**

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("cypFiltered",
  function(message) {

   var table = document.getElementById(message);
   var range = document.createRange();  
   range.selectNode(table);
   window.getSelection().addRange(range);
   
  document.execCommand('copy');
  }
);
```

The results are not perfect since it contains other HTML elements that makes part of this id, but it seems to work. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ? I suppose this is not really elegant to rely on an `id` we have to look for in the `Inspector tab` and that can vary depending on the number of rows that are filtered.

Also, I noticed that `navigator.clipboard.write()` should be used instead of the deprecated `document.execCommand('copy');`. But I cannot find how to implement this since it looks like a BLOB object is necessary and I'm not sure how to convert.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the need to copy-and-paste into Word.  Why not write the object presented in the table directly into Word with (eg) officer or markdown or quarto?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just quite a newb, I'm not aware of these packages. Does that mean I could have a simple method called by a button that would allow me to insert the datatable keeping all formatted text (bold, columns, etc) where I want in a Word document ? As a note, the word document will contain other elements, I need to be able to specificy where I would like to "paste" my datatable. Is that possible ? I don't want to export the datatable as a doc file. I really need to be able to insert the object somewhere in an already existing Word doc.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  [Rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) is better for generating new Word documents,  [officer](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/) for manipulating existing word documents.  Also consider [quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html), which is superseding Rmarkdown.  Other options exist.  You can even embed markdown in Shiny apps.  Or embed a Shiny app in a markdown document.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at `officer`, but I cannot really understand how it could be at least almost as "efficient" as a basic copy-paste button. The idea is to be able to quickly copy the content of a datatable into a place we want in a Word file. From what I have understood so far reading the documention of `officer/officedown`, it could be possible to update a table in a Word document. But I cannot find example/tutorial showing how to get/update a datatable in a Shiny app online and have it quickly exported in a Word document without having to download something. Am I wrong ?