# How to preserve colspan attributes of DT when exporting to xlsx within an RMD file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, dt

I have a sample RMD that includes a DT with a custom container. My issue is that, I'm unable to download the DT into an excel format that preserves the main column headers as they encompass child headers.

In the example, below "Sepal" and "Petal" do not show up in the final output when using the Buttons extension.

[image]

Additionally, I've attempted to rework this solution. ([R datatable buttons export with formated cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966732/r-datatable-buttons-export-with-formated-cells/54350639#54350639)). But am unable to get it properly working within the context of an RMD vs shiny.

The solution above requires the following files to be in the same directory as the rmd. Which I'm using in my rmd.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.5/xlsx.core.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/5.2.0/js/tableexport.min.js

Right now, it doesn't look like the table ID, `myID`, is retrieved when knitting to html. However, when running the js chunk code directly in the browser console after it has been knit (using console via inspector), it does pull the correct element.

```
# Init result
$table
S.fn.init(0)


# Result from running in console after file has been knit
var $table = $('#myID').find('table');
$table
S.fn.init [table#DataTables_Table_0.display.fill-container.dataTable.no-footer, prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]
```

Then when exporting, ONLY the main headers are included but no actual data is there.

I'm open to any solutions that either solve this issue directly. OR if there's a way to keep the table as is on the front end and then create a psuedo download button that downloads the original data.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
    orientation: rows
---

<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="tableexport.min.js"></script>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
```

Preserve Colspans
=======================================  

### my table

```{r}
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(# this is missing in the clipboard excel: 
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))

datatable(iris[1:5, c(5, 1:4)],
          container = sketch, 
          rownames = FALSE, 
          elementId = "myID",
          extensions = c('Buttons'),
          options = list(dom = 'B',
                         buttons = list(
                           list(extend = "excel", filename = "Test_excel"))
                         ))

```

```{js, echo=FALSE}

(function() {

  var $table = $('#myID').find('table');
  console.log($table)
  
  <!-- var instance = $table.tableExport({ -->
  <!--   formats: ['xlsx'], -->
  <!--   filename: 'myTable', -->
  <!--   sheetname: 'Sheet1' -->
  <!-- }); -->
  
  var instance = $table.tableExport();
  
  var exportData0 = instance.getExportData();
  
  var exportData = exportData0[Object.keys(exportData0)[0]]['xlsx'];
  
  instance.export2file(exportData.data, exportData.mimeType, exportData.filename, 
                       exportData.fileExtension, exportData.merges, 
                       exportData.RTL, exportData.sheetname);
})();
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this. But you have to set `runtime:shiny`. ***Edit*** wrong, `runtime:shiny` is not necessary; just include `library(shiny)`.

And there is a JavaScript error detected by the developer tools, but it seems it is harmless.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="tableexport.min.js"></script>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
```

```{js}
var js_export = function() {
var $table = $("#myID").find('table');
var instance = $table.tableExport({
  formats: ['xlsx'],
  exportButtons: false,
  filename: 'myTable',
  sheetname: 'Sheet1'
});
var exportData0 = instance.getExportData();
var exportData = exportData0[Object.keys(exportData0)[0]]['xlsx'];
instance.export2file(exportData.data, exportData.mimeType, exportData.filename, 
                     exportData.fileExtension, exportData.merges, 
                     exportData.RTL, exportData.sheetname);
} 
```

```{r}
actionButton("export", "Export table", onClick="js_export()")
```




Preserve Colspans
=======================================  

### my table

```{r}
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(# this is missing in the clipboard excel: 
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))

datatable(iris[1:5, c(5, 1:4)],
          container = sketch, 
          rownames = FALSE, 
          elementId = "myID",
          extensions = c('Buttons'),
          options = list(dom = 'B',
                         buttons = list(
                           list(extend = "excel", filename = "Test_excel"))
                         ))
br()
```
````

Comment: Appreciate the response. Unfortunately, I need to do this without `runtime: shiny`. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @Jamie In fact I didn't try without `runtime:shiny`. Maybe it works.

Comment: @Jamie Yes it works !!!! You just have to include `library(shiny)`, but not `runtime:shiny`.

Comment: Sweet deal, thanks for putting that together!